# Access type, path, and value from dynamic import

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, deno, dynamic-import

I'm looking for a way to type the argument to `example`, Currently this code just sets it to `any`. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAigGzgUwjAkgWwAcEAnGZAHgBVlMAPGbAEwGdkWYS4IBzAPgAUANwBcyKgEpkAb2DJUSDshKYWCNEMzIAvMgFTtfZHCKkYwiXOQwAnoS0AlVes1OYYEil0BBAO4BDOEYmCjcPCCo7TApbewQQZWcNTD4%20KyhFcnp-IjQtXWF-NDBMMSc1ZLDPAyNZeXkVd09kISKSqwBfK0bwmSt5Qn8YAAsxIQAafsSKzUn62jocwjzO4C7gDIglbNz85H8WG2g9Gr75zaVpZEGR8emXTDud5a0OnVQMbDxTMgEAcgAdAB6dBYHAAfQyTEwAJgLDof0s50U6hhaAQPAEN2GSPqF3IQne-gCQXuyX0UyBQPmAD0APxTZ55CyU6nIelrIA)

```
function clientImport <T extends string>(v: T) {
  const resolve = () => import(v)
  type ResolveReturn = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof resolve>>
  const example = (value: ResolveReturn) => {
    return value
  }
  return {
    path: v,
    resolve,
    example
  }
}

const example = async () => {
    const { path, resolve, example } = clientImport('./client_code.tsx')
    console.log(path)
    const v = await resolve()
    //    ^?
    example(v)
    //  ^?
}
```

I want this typed:

```
function clientImport <T extends string>(v: T) {
  return function <Z>(x: (q: T) => Promise<Z>) {
    return {
      resolve: () => x(v),
      path: v
    }
  }
}


const v = await clientImport('../examples/client_code/example.ts')(p => import(p))
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible since `import` is not generic.

Answer (score 1):

With a build-step (think prisma) you can create a function that is auto-generated:

```
function _clientImport <G>(
  path: string,
  code: () => Promise<G>
) {
  return { path, code }
}

// this would be auto-generated
const library = {
  '../examples/client_code/example.ts': _clientImport(
    import.meta.resolve('../examples/client_code/example.ts'),
    () => import('../examples/client_code/example.ts')
  )
}

function clientImport (p: keyof typeof library) {
  return library[p]
}

const g = clientImport('../examples/client_code/example.ts')
```